# Handling very large numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I need to write a simple program that calculates a mathematical formula.
The only problem here is that one of the variables can take the value 10^100.
Because of this I can not write this program in C++/C (I can't use external libraries like gmp).
Few hours ago I read that Python is capable of calculating such values.
My question is:
Why

```
print("%.10f"%(10.25**100))
```

is returning the number `"118137163510621843218803309161687290343217035128100169109374848108012122824436799009169146127891562496.0000000000"`

instead of 
`"118137163510621850716311252946961817841741635398513936935237985161753371506358048089333490072379307296.453937046171461"`?

Comment: Besides the answers below, there is also the issue of your string formatting code.  You specifically asked for 10 digits after the decimal point.  Why would you expect 15 digits in the output?  Also, keep in mind that using `%` for printing *actually converts* the value according to the specifier.  So even if you use the `decimal` module, if you print it using `%.10f`, Python will convert the value to `float` first, and you will still get the same result.

Comment: Just FYI, Python floats are the same as C doubles, and have 53 bits of precision (on almost all platforms).  That's about 16 or 17 decimal digits.  That's why the two results you showed don't agree after that many decimal digits at their starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Python uses a fixed precision floating-point data type to represent fractional numbers (just like `double` in C). You can work with [precise rational numbers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html), though:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction("10.25")
Fraction(41, 4)
>>> x = Fraction("10.25")
>>> x**100
Fraction(189839102486063226543090986563273122284619337618944664609359292215966165735102377674211649585188827411673346619890309129617784863285653302296666895356073140724001, 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376)
```

You can also use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal) module if you want arbitrary precision decimals (only numbers that are representable as finite decimals are supported, though):

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 150
>>> Decimal("10.25")**100
Decimal('118137163510621850716311252946961817841741635398513936935237985161753371506358048089333490072379307296.453937046171460995169093650913476028229144848989')
```

Comment: @Bakuriu: Not at all. `decimal` cannot represent arbitrary rational numbers.

Comment: I already know that, but the OP probably does not need to represent arbitrary rational numbers, but numbers with a certain precision. `decimal` is the right tool for this. `decimal` can be *order of magnitudes* faster than using `Fraction`s. The only limitation is that you must have some known bounds for the numbers (which you can do most of the time) and setup the correct context.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I just, too, noticed that OPs output is also not precise. As for speed, I usually opt for best-possible correctness first (especially when I am suggesting solutions on a public platform) and try to find a faster solution when I figure out through profiling that this is really necessary. Anyways, I added a `decimal` example because OP is probably actually more interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

Python is capable of handling arbitrarily large *integers*, but not floating point values. They can get pretty large, but as you noticed, you lose precision in the low digits.